# Wordpress- server configuration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

after configuring my WordPress on my big rock server, when i am trying to install new themes or plugins i am getting the below error message? I am just able to see the default templates but not other featured or popular themes or plugins.

> it  An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.

Comment: Check if your files on your server are writeable by the web server. Stack Overflow is probably not the best support forum for this kind of problem.

Comment: thank you,  i have given Files 664 permission. should I change it.